# Bokeh server plot does not update

Tags: server, bokeh

LS, 
All the answers about the same topic did not help me solve my update problem. I think it has to do with the dfs = df.sort_values(by=['E']). I use all the latest versions of the libraries. The examples on the bokeh website work fine on my configuration. Via an update button I want to allow the user to select the prefered sort order. The two other sort buttons will be added when this part works.
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.models import Button

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=["AMS", "LHR", "FRA", "PTY", "CGD"], S=[7,-5,-3,3,2], E=[8,3,-2,5,8], C=[5,2,7,-3,-4]))

source = ColumnDataSource(df)

options = dict(plot_width=300, plot_height=200,
               tools="pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,box_select,lasso_select")

button = Button(label="Change Sort to E")

p1 = figure(y_range=source.data['A'].tolist(), title="S", **options)
p1.hbar(y='A', right="S", height=0.2, source=source)


p2 = figure(y_range=source.data['A'].tolist(), title="E", **options)
p2.hbar(y="A", right="E", height=0.2, source=source)


p3 = figure(y_range=source.data['A'].tolist(), title="C", **options)
p3.hbar(y="A", right="C", height=0.2, source=source)


def update():
    dfs = df.sort_values(by=['E'])
    source.data = ColumnDataSource.from_df(dfs)


button.on_click(update)

p = gridplot([[button], [p1, p2, p3]], toolbar_location="right")

curdoc().add_root(p)
```

I run the server via: bokeh serve --show app.py --port 5009

Thank you very much for making the update work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the order of things on a categorical axis, you have to update the *range*. The order of the factors on the axis is specified exactly by the order of factors you configure for the range, so you will need to re-order the factors to match the sort order you want. So, something like:

```
p1.y_range.factors = new_sorted_factors
```

See

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#sorted

for a complete (standalone) example.